# How do I check if I have packet socket support enabled in my distro's kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, ethernet, packet

How do I check that packet socket support has been compiled into my kernel? I'm running Crunchbang, a Debian-based distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Linux distributions include the config parameters used to compile the kernel in `/boot/config-<kernel-version>`.

So

```
grep -x 'CONFIG_PACKET=[ym]' "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"
```

Should tell you if `AF_PACKET` socket support is included (`m` for *as a module*).

Otherwise, you can just try and create a socket (using `socket(2)`, see `packet(7)` for how to do it) in the AF_PACKET family and check if reports an error.